# Jasmine mockability of imported vs required named exports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jasmine, babeljs, commonjs

I'll start with the setup, before I get into the problem. Let's start with the base file whose named exports we'll want to spy on:

```
// fileA.js
export function bar() {}
export function foo() {}
```

And then have two variations of classes that import these, one in CommonJS style, and one in ES6 style:

```
// es6Baz.js
import * as A from 'fileA'

export default class Baz {
  callFoo() { A.foo(); }
}

// commonBaz.js
const A = require('fileA');

export default class Baz {
  callFoo() { A.foo(); }
}
```

Then likewise, test files for these two same variants:

```
// testEs6A.js
import Baz from 'es6Baz';
import * as A from 'fileA';    

it('test', () => {
  spyOn(A, 'foo');
  const b = new Baz();
  b.callFoo();
  expect(A.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();  // this will fail
});

// testCommonA.js
import Baz from 'es6Baz';
const A = require('fileA');   

it('test', () => {
  spyOn(A, 'foo');
  const b = new Baz();
  b.callFoo();
  expect(A.foo).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this will pass
});
```

**The main question here is**: why does mocking work with the CommonJS approach, but not the ES6 one, assuming we're using Babel to compile?

My understanding was that ES6 live binds, while CommonJS copies, so I was surprised the former failed, and even more surprised the latter succeeded. My best guess is that a * import results in a locally namespaced object that's different in the files this is done in (i.e. `A` in `es6Baz.js` is not the same as `A` in `testEst6A.js`), but is that actually the case? And why would the `require` work, when this doesn't?

Comment: This depends on how is the app being built, this isn't explained. The thing you're describing will happen if native ES modules are used. By default Babel falls back to CJS, https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=PTAEDMEsBsFMEEB0ArAzgKFgDwA4HsAnAFwgFcA7AYyMj3NACMBDAgCgEpQBvAX010IlwFarXrg8eDtz7pIAW3zFQAKlBNUoeBAJ55oAORQ48A0A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=Node-6.9&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2 .

Comment: Both import and require are expected to behave similarly. Any way, for tests I'd go with require because it's more flexible and can occur in test blocks.

Comment: @estus to be clear, you mean the inability to mock will happen if using native ES modules, and will be avoided if you leave Babel to it's CJS defaults?

The problem with using the require approach is that in my testing, the require needed to be done in both the test file AND the original file for the mocking to work, which isn't super desirable.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. It's unlikely that you will want to use native modules with Babel, especially in tests, so it's not a big deal. But this still may be an issue depending on how the app is being bundled, athough I'm unaware of conditions that can affect that (IIRC, Webpack never makes module exports read-only). So it's still unclear what causes the problem.